# What is the best way to seperate routing tables in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm building a lab environment with multiple routing devices and 2 Ubuntu machines as clients (22.04.2). The ubuntu machines need to act as 8 independent clients (from networking point of view) because the core network is separated by VRFs.

The ubuntu machines connect to a switch which separates the traffic with 802.1Q trunking so these clients will receive traffic on multiple different VLANs. My problem is that the clients need to have a default route for each vlan, which not possible in a single routing table.

How can I separate the IP traffic? I'm not very experienced in linux I read about VRFs and namespaces as options, but maybe you know other solutions. What would you recommend?

**Update**:
This solution works pretty fine, but I'm still interested what are the alternatives.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/netplan# more 00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  vrfs:
    RED-vrf:
      table: 10
      interfaces: [ens4.10]

    BLUE-vrf:
      table: 20
      interfaces: [ens4.20]
  

  ethernets:
    ens4: {}


  vlans:
    ens4.10:
      id: 10
      link: ens4
      addresses: [10.0.0.2/30]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.0.0.1

    ens4.20:
      id: 20
      link: ens4
      addresses: [20.0.0.2/30]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 20.0.0.1
  version: 2
```

Comment: Is it an option to implement these clients as 8 separate virtual machines?

Comment: Honestly, I would like to avoid that.